# bqplot: performance issue

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bqplot

I was playing around with `on_drag` features of `bqplot`. and I noticed that it is slightly lagging.. 
I am not sure if this is

- real issue
- I do something inappropriate
- meant to work like it is

so the code I have is the following

```
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig=plt.figure()
lin=plt.plot([0,1],
             [0,0])
scatt1=plt.scatter([0],[0],colors=['Red'])
scatt2=plt.scatter([1],[0],enable_move=True)

plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
fig.layout.height = '500px'
fig.layout.width = '500px'
plt.show()
def call_back2(name, value):
   #print(value,name)
   if value['point']:
       X=value['point']['x']
       Y=value['point']['y']
       lin.x=[scatt1.x[0],(X-scatt1.x)[0]]
       lin.y=[scatt1.y[0],(Y-scatt1.y)[0]]

scatt2.on_drag_start(call_back2)
scatt2.on_drag(call_back2)
scatt2.on_drag_end(call_back2)
```

it is simply two points connected
and you can drag the blue one around
what I notice is that the line ever so slightly lags behind the blue dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly drag a point on a line.  Your method is only way to do it that I know of and so the line will always follow the scatter point.   I couldn't get your code to go noticeably faster.

```
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
lin=plt.plot([0,1],
             [0,0])
scatt1=plt.scatter([0],[0],colors=['Red'])
scatt2=plt.scatter([1],[0],enable_move=True)
# scatt2.update_on_move = True

plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
fig.layout.height = '500px'
fig.layout.width = '500px'
plt.show()
def call_back2(name, value):
#     with lin.hold_sync():
   lin.x=[lin.x[0], value['point']['x']]
   lin.y=[lin.y[0], value['point']['y']]    

# scatt2.on_drag_start(call_back2)
scatt2.on_drag(call_back2 )
# scatt2.on_drag_end(call_back2)
```

#### Edit:

Actually it can be done.  Use jslink.  The traits must be the same type and length/size. In this case, the 'x' and 'y' traits for the line and scatter marks are arrays of length 2.

```py
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import jslink

fig = plt.figure()

# Strange bug when 1st point is 0,0. Red point flickers.  
lin=plt.plot([0.0001,1],
             [0.0001,0])   

scatt2=plt.scatter(lin.x, lin.y, enable_move = True, colors = ['Red','blue'])
scatt2.update_on_move = True

# Cover up 1st point so it can't be moved. 
# Just remove this line if you want both points to be moveable
scatt3=plt.scatter([lin.x[0]], [lin.y[0]], colors = ['Red']) 


plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
fig.layout.height = '500px'
fig.layout.width = '500px'
plt.show()

jslink((scatt2, 'x'), (lin, 'x'))
jslink((scatt2, 'y'), (lin, 'y'))
```

Jslink doesn't need the Python kernel for the interactivity to work. 
You you can create a html file (and js directory) by:

```
import ipyvolume.embed
ipyvolume.embed.embed_html("bqplot.html", fig, offline=True, devmode=False)
```

Comment: thanks, so it seems that "meant to work like it is
" :)

Comment: Maybe there is a way to jslink the scatt2.x and the lin.x[1]. The bqplot gitter channel is probably the best place to go for help.

Comment: I asked the same question there as well, and some people suggested to post here as well :)

Comment: Hi @DougR, it is indeed faster, however I do not understand how the  generated html works. For some reason if I put the statically generated html and the accompanying js folder to some place I do not get anything rendnered in the browser. Anyway I might be better to move this discussion back to gitter. Thanks for your help again!